# How to access dynamic VF field and parse it

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to access this dynamically generated multi picklist in apex and how to parse it if I have a docID;docName;docFormat for each entry?

Thanks

```
<apex:outputPanel id="op">
<apex:outputLabel id="slDMlabel" value="Select Template" for="slDM"/>&nbsp;
<apex:selectList id="slDM" value="{!selectedMain}" size="3" multiselect="true" rendered="true" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!mainOptions}" /> 
</apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: when I say parse it I mean how to get each entry from the multi picklist, and get each of the 3 values in an entry so I can do something with it?

Comment: use javascript to get all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-select picklist SObject field uses the semi-colon as the separator between each selected item. So if the value is ever to be saved in an SObject field change your separator to something else (that is unlikely to be in any of the parts) e.g.:

```
docID::::docName::::docFormat
```

Then to parse (assuming `selectedMain` `is String[]`):

```
for (String selectedItem : selectedMain) {
    String[] parts = selectedItem.split('::::');
    String docID = parts[0];
    String docName = parts[1];
    String docFormat = parts[2];
    // Do something with the parts of each item here
}
```

If you were presenting the multi-select picklist field directly in the page then the first line would change to:

```
for (String selectedItem : sob.MultiSelectField__c.split(';')) {
```